# Maven multi-project depths

Tags: maven

I was trying to build Maven pom in something similar to the following hierarchical form:

root

+-- A-POM

+-- B-POM

+-- C-POM

+---D-POM

I was hoping that this could take care of my changed module problem. That is, if C is changed, then A must be rebuilt, etc.

But I ran into the issue that it seems the packaging at root is "pom," and after that I can't have A as packaging "war" then continue to drill in to have A include B, C as its modules. It seems to me that any POM which does not have "pom" in the  then it can't have child modules. Is my understanding correct? Is there a way to do what I wanted to do?

In addition, I don't seem about to chain the "changed" mechanism in Maven (must due to my lack of knowledge). I like to have Maven detect a dependent project has changed and rebuild all the affected projects.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reactor project (the root of the multimodule project) must have pom packaging. So your nested structure is invalid since A is not of type pom and I'm pretty sure you won't get it to work this way.

Second point is that Maven is a modularized build system and uses repository mechanisms to locate pre-built artifacts instead of checking out all modules from version control and building them in a monolithic way like in the old days ;) This means that Maven cannot know what to rebuild when you change something at your module since it simple does not have all the other module there at this time.

I think this is more a CI task than that should be handled by the build system itself. I know that your can achieve such a behavior with an appropriate build/CI Server like Jenkins that supports upstream and downstream projects. This means it is able to detect dependencies between the projects and trigger other builds as soon as a dependency has been built. This comes close to the behavior you are trying to achieve.

Btw. rebuilding other projects is only required for SNAPSHOT dependencies. Jenkins with the maven plugin supports this behavior but, depending on the number of SNAPSHOT dependencies of your project, this can cause long chains of project builds on the server. Some folks are of the opinion that in general SNAPSHOT versions are hell for CI tasks since these artifacts can change over time and are not reproducible. You could think over completely omitting SNAPSHOT versions and building final versions each time. This would also obviate your requirement to rebuild other modules as soon as a module changes. There are simply no changes until you upgrade dependency versions.

Comment: Hi Shi - Thanks so much for clearing my head for the use of Maven. Yes I did use Jenkins to work the dependencies in the build process. So it sounds like when developers use Maven they pretty much manage their own order of builds?

Comment: Yes that's my experience with Maven. In a small perfect world everything is fine with Maven but as soon as it comes to large real worl projects with dozens of modules and libraries or migration from older build systems, you struggle with dependencies, build lifecycle aso. I could tell you stories about a migration of a monolithic application from Ant to maven... Puh ;)